# How can I drop columns in a loop in RStudio?

Tags: r

I have tables A, B, and C, and they all have columns X, Y, and Z,

I would like to drop columns in a loop from different tables.

My code is as follows

```
for (i in c(A, B, C)) {
  for (j in c(X, Y, Z)) {
    (i$j <- NULL)
  }
}
```

My error message tells objects X,Y,Z weren't found. I believe my problem is in lack of use of apostrophes in tables and column names, but doing so yields the error message "Coercing LHS to a list"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can place the datasets in a `list`, loop over the `list` with `lapply`, select the columns, assign (`<-`) to NULL and return the data. Here, `function(x)` is the lambda function

```
lst1 <- lapply(list(A, B, C), function(x) {x[c('X', 'Y', 'Z')] <- NULL; x})
```

The return output is a `list` of datasets.  If we want to update the original objects, use `list2env`:

```
names(lst1) <- c("A", "B", "C")
list2env(lst1, .GlobalEnv)
```

---

Using a `for` loop, we can avoid the nested loop as the assignment to NULL is vectorized.  We loop over the object names as a string and `get` the value of the object. Assign the columns to NULL and update the original object:

```
for(nm in c("A", "B", "C")) {
    # // Get the value of dataset
    tmp <- get(nm)
    # // Assign columns to NULL
    tmp[c("X", "Y", "Z")] <- NULL
    # // Update the original object
    assign(nm, tmp)
 }
```

Comment: This solution solves my problem, thank you very much!

Comment: A variant to the given for loop could be: `for(i in c("A", "B", "C")) {assign(i, `[<-`(get(i), c("X", "Y", "Z"), value=NULL))}`

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option but not recommended (better by using the [@akrun's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65723957/12158757))

```
eval(
  str2expression(
    paste0(
      sprintf("%s['%s']<-NULL", c("A", "B", "C"), c("X", "Y", "Z")),
      collapse = ";"
    )
  )
)
```